# Is there a way to import processing.py or processing.js as Python module for Django web development?

Tags: python, django, image-processing, processing, interactive

I am trying to develop interactive web content using processing on Python Django. But I can't locate any material showing how to import processing.py or processing.js as a python module for Django development.

Comment: if `processing.py`  is located on the path then just `import processing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to include the processing.js in your html template ... this has nothing to do with python or anyother language and is just about how to include script src tags in your html

```
<html>
<head>

<!-- Include processing complete js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.0/p5.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<h4>Hello World!</h4>
<script>
  // do some processing.js stuff here ...
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`processing.py` is used to render desktop processing programs in python(using pygame or maybe just OpenGL) ... if you want web you need js ...